# Bootstrap 4 Carousel Button Display Issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I have two instances of the Bootstrap 4 carousel component running, both of which have essentially the same markup but totally different displays: one has its button states display as .5 opaque, hard-bordered rectangles with the prev and next "chevron" buttons hidden in them.

Here is an example that works:

```
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ul class="carousel-indicators" style="list-style: none;">
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/01.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
    <div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/02.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
    <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/03.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></button>
```

And here is what that looks like:
[image]

Here's the markup for the broken example:

```
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ul class="carousel-indicators" style="list-style: none;">
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="active" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/0002365.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
    <div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/0002364.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
    <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="/foo/0002363.jpeg" alt="testing" /></div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></button>
```

And here's how it displays:
[image]

I have tried to force new button styles on those "prev" and "next" rectangular buttons, but that impacts the spans, as well,  and I clearly don't need to on the first example which displays perfectly. I'm stumped: why does one work fine and the other's broken? Thanks for any help you can provide me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't track down the styling anomalies, I at least know why they're happening: the working example is using Bootstrap 4.6.2, whereas the broken example was using Bootstrap 4.0.0. I'm not the application architect, so it wasn't my decision, but v. obv. Bootstrap 4.6.2 component markup is more likely to run into problems of this sort if the library actually being used is Bootstrap 4.0.0. I'll leave this question up in the event other people run into the same issue.